# Conditionally calculate the required aggregates using data.table

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

Consider following snippet:

```
library("data.table")
dT <- data.table(keyCol=sample(x = c("A", "B", "C"), size = 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 valCol=rpois(n = 20, lambda=10))
# head(dT)

keyCol  valCol
<chr>   <int>
A   11
C   14
C   9
B   9
C   11
C   10
```

I want to calculate some aggregates (unique count of `valCol`, number of rows) grouping `keyCol` column:

```
res <- dT[, .(unique__=length(unique(valCol)), count__=.N), by="keyCol"]
# res

keyCol  unique__    count__
<chr>   <int>   <int>
A   4   4
C   5   8
B   6   8
```

But I want to calculate these aggregates conditionally, i.e. sometimes I want unique only, sometimes I want count only, and sometimes I want both. One possible solution is to use multiple `if else` conditions:

```
getCount <- TRUE
getUnique <- TRUE
aggColName <- "valCol"

if(getCount & getUnique){
    res <- dT[, .(unique__=length(unique(valCol)), count__=.N), by="keyCol"]
} else if (getCount){
    res <- dT[, .(count__=.N), by="keyCol"]
} else {
    res <- dT[, .(unique__=length(unique(valCol))), by="keyCol"]    
}
# res

keyCol  unique__    count__
<chr>   <int>   <int>
A   4   4
C   5   8
B   6   8
```

Coming from Python background, above `if else` ladder seems like writing bunch of redundant codes. For example, on pandas, we can pass tuple containing the column names, and aggregate functions, or we can unpack a dictionary containing column name, and aggregate functions.

Is there simple way of doing the same using `data.table`, i.e. passing column names, and aggregates function using some variables, or passing them conditionally?

Comment: Yes, there is new 'env' argument which let's you parameterize virtually everything, even names in LHS which are not easily customizable in base R and requires extra setNames call.

Comment: For the use of `aggColName`, until 1.14.3 is released (which brings the `env=` argument), one can do `get(aggColName)`; further, `length(unique(.))` in canonical data.table can be reduced, resulting in `unique__ = uniqueN(get(aggColName))`.

Comment: @r2evans, thank you for your valuable comment, I'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your specific example is a bit tricky because `.N` is not a function,
it's a symbol.
I'll come back to that later,
but let's first assume you only have functions.
You could write your own helper that helps you achieve what you want:

```
helper <- function(dt, by, colNames, funs) {
    dt[, by = by, .SDcols = colNames, Map(funs, .SD, f = function(fn, col) {
        fn(col)
    })]
}

helper(dT, "keyCol", "valCol", list(
    unique__ = function(x) { length(unique(x)) }
))
#    keyCol unique__
# 1:      B        8
# 2:      A        4
# 3:      C        2

helper(dT, "keyCol", "valCol", list(
    max__ = max
))
#    keyCol max__
# 1:      B    13
# 2:      A    11
# 3:      C    13

helper(dT, "keyCol", "valCol", list(
    unique__ = function(x) { length(unique(x)) },
    max__ = max
))
#    keyCol unique__ max__
# 1:      B        8    13
# 2:      A        4    11
# 3:      C        2    13
```

With the helper, you can provide different number of columns by specifing `.SDcols`,
and `Map` applies the functions you supply.

However, you must know that `data.table` can often optimize calls based on what it "sees",
and hiding some logic behind `helper` means you may lose that.
Take this example:

```
dT[, max(valCol), by = keyCol, verbose = TRUE]
Detected that j uses these columns: valCol 
Finding groups using forderv ... forder.c received 20 rows and 1 columns
0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
Getting back original order ... forder.c received a vector type 'integer' length 3
0.000s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'max(valCol)'
GForce optimized j to 'gmax(valCol)'
Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE) ... gforce initial population of grp took 0.000
gforce assign high and low took 0.000
gforce eval took 0.000
0.000s elapsed (0.001s cpu) 
   keyCol V1
1:      B 13
2:      A 11
3:      C 13
```

You see there `GForce TRUE`.
If you enable verbosity in the call within `helper`,
you'll notice `GForce` is always `FALSE`.

Now, regarding `.N`, you could also write a helper for that and "wrap" the symbol with a function,
but it's honestly kind of hacky.
My version simply searches for `.N` in the stack's environments until it finds it
(so it assumes `data.table` will have computed that at some point in the stack,
which in this case is true, YMMV).

```
count <- function(ignored) {
    n <- 1L
    e <- parent.frame(n)
    ans <- get0(".N", e, inherits = FALSE)
    while (is.null(ans) && !identical(e, .GlobalEnv)) {
        n <- n + 1L
        e <- parent.frame(n)
        ans <- get0(".N", e, inherits = FALSE)
    }
    ans
}

helper(dT, "keyCol", "valCol", list(
    unique__ = function(x) { length(unique(x)) },
    count__ = count
))
#    keyCol unique__ count__
# 1:      B        8      10
# 2:      A        4       6
# 3:      C        2       4
```

Comment: Thank you Alexis for your detailed answer. I'll give it a try

Answer (score 2):

This might not be quite what you're looking for, but maybe it will get you started.

```
library("data.table")

dt <- data.table(keyCol=sample(x = c("A", "B", "C"), size = 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 valCol1=rpois(n = 20, lambda=10),
                 valCol2=sample(20))

chrVals <- rep(c("valCol1", "valCol2"), each = 3)
lFuns <- rep(list(length, uniqueN, sum), 2)
nms <- c("length1", "unique1", "sum1", "length2", "unique2", "sum2")

dt[, setNames(lapply(seq_along(chrVals), function(i) lFuns[[i]](.SD[[i]])), nms), .SDcols = chrVals, by = "keyCol"]
#>    keyCol length1 unique1 sum1 length2 unique2 sum2
#> 1:      B       4       3   46       4       4   39
#> 2:      C      11       9  104      11      11  129
#> 3:      A       5       5   39       5       5   42

idx <- c(1,3:5)
dt[, setNames(lapply(idx, function(i) lFuns[[i]](.SD[[i]])), nms[idx]), .SDcols = chrVals, by = "keyCol"]
#>    keyCol length1 sum1 length2 unique2
#> 1:      B       4   46       4       4
#> 2:      C      11  104      11      11
#> 3:      A       5   39       5       5
```

Comment: Thank you jBlood for your answer, I'll try it